# How to use password protection with the Linux tar command?

Tags: linux, tar

How can I use password protection with the `tar` command in Linux? I'm new to Linux so please explain to me with simple usage.

Answer (score 15):

As far as I know tar doesn't provide this service. You could use 7zip instead, which does offer encrypted archives.

What you can also do is use `gpg` in addition to tar:

```
tar cvJf myarchive.tar.xz myfiles
gpg -c myarchive.tar.xz.gpg
```

This will give you a password protected archive.

Comment: hi thanks a lot, can you elaborate a little bit about this command       __tar cvJf myarchive.tar.xz myfiles
       gpg -c myarchive.tar.xz.gpg__
Sorry I'm new to Linux.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on the linux command line. This is basic stuff.

Comment: Thanks again !!! Can you point me some good tutorial ?

Comment: In addition, look at the links of this page: http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/bbnkp/ive_tinkered_in_ubuntu_before_but_its_the_primary/c0lzpwk

Comment: This is two answers.

Answer (score 7):

Run the output through pgp

```
tar .... | pgp --symmetric output.tar.pgp
```

decrypt:

```
pgp -d output.tar.gz | tar tv
```

Consider using proper asymmetric keys (public/private keys) for real protection

Comment: @sehe - Thanks a lot. But unluckily, I don't understand what you had written. Can you tell me a bit more detail? Thanks !!!

Comment: @kevin: To my understanding, a "symmetric key" is a plain-old password-based system, like you're familiar with. An asymmetric key system has two "passwords" or keys, a public and a private one. You can share the public one freely, and people use this to identify you. The private key is the part that proves that you are you, so sharing it is a Bad Thing. Anyhow, the symmetric key is almost certainly what you want, since it's much simpler, although the asymmetric key is more secure, in theory.

Answer (score 4):

To zip a file with password run the following command:

`zip -er name.zip folder/`

It will show a prompt to enter a hidden password.

---

To unzip the file, run:

`unzip name.zip`

And enter the password you added before.

Answer (score 3):

### Simple way

Step 1 : `sudo apt-get install zip` 
Step 2 : `zip -P password file.zip files`

Comment: the password will show in history of commands .